# Screen orientation not working in android GingerBread

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Accelerometer sensors for android2.3.3 ,
i am able to get successfully get the accelerometer X,Y,Z values, but
when i am trying to rotate the screen from portrait to landscape mode
i am not able to view the display properly.Althought the
functrionalaities are working(i.e. If i am touching and dragging at
the top i am able to observe in the logs that notifications bar is
getting opened)

Kindly find the logcat  details"

```
I/WindowManager( 1474): Setting rotation to 3, animFlags=0
E/libEGL  ( 1474): eglDestroyImageKHR:1811 error 300c
(EGL_BAD_PARAMETER)
I/ActivityManager( 1474): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0
loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17
seq=6}
D/dalvikvm( 1556): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 154K, 48% free 2963K/5639K,
external 5050K/5062K, paused 29ms
D/dalvikvm( 1556): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 55K, 48% free 2959K/5639K,
external 3527K/3887K, paused 37ms

[  117.071594] mcde_display_dpi mcde_display_dpi.0:
try_video_mode:Failed to find video mode x=480, y=800
E/gralloc ( 1474): FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO failed
```

Can you kindly let me know what might be the possible  reason behind
this.